# Getting an uncopyable object out of a try

Tags: c++, try-catch, scoping

I have the following class:

```
class ShaderProgram {
    private:
        GLuint shaderProgram;
        std::string getCompilationError(GLuint shader);
        std::string getLinkingError(GLuint shaderProgram);

    public:
        // ! Might throw exception !
        ShaderProgram(const std::string &vertexShaderPath, const std::string &fragmentShaderPath);
        ~ShaderProgram();
        // Delete the copy constructor and assignment operator, you should not copy this class
        ShaderProgram(const ShaderProgram&) = delete;
        ShaderProgram* operator=(const ShaderProgram&) = delete;
        // We do allow move constructor and move assignment
        ShaderProgram(ShaderProgram&& other);
        ShaderProgram& operator=(ShaderProgram&&);
};
```

You are not allowed to copy and instance of this class because of the `GLuint shaderProgram`: this needs to be deleted exactly once, so if one makes copies of a `ShaderProgram` object and one of the copies destructs, all of them are unusable.

Now the constructor might throw. For example: if the file is not found or if there are errors during glsl compilation/linking. I want to catch these errors, print a nice error message and exit the program. If there is no error, I can carry on, but I am stuck getting the object out of the try scope. The only solution I see is to use pointers:

```
ShaderProgram* program;

try {
    program = new ShaderProgram("PATH", "PATH");

} catch (Exception e) {
    // print error
    // Exit the program
}
// code
delete program;
```

But now I have to manually call delete, which I do not want to do unless I really have to. To fix that, I can use a `unique_ptr` or something, but I feel like there should be a more proper solution.

Another possibilty is to just stick all code that uses the `ShaderProgram` inside the `try`. The `ShaderProgram` lives very long and thus this would lead to a very large `try` block. This could make the code harder to read.

I feel like there should be a more proper solution. What would that solution be?

Comment: I don't really see the problem. Isn't all the code that uses the created instance also inside the `try` block? I mean if you got an exception then there is no object that you could use after the try block

Comment: This object is very long-lived, so that a lot of code would end up in the try catch. This is offcourse possible, but it makes the code harder to read.

Comment: I'd say you are trying to catch the exception in the wrong place. As I said before, all the code that comes afer the `try` cannot use the object when it was not sucessfully created

Comment: That is indeed true, the catch would print an error and exit the program: we cannot recover from this error.

Comment: ok, please add that to the question. It changes the situation. "handle them nicely"  is usually not terminating the application ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to terminate when the exception occurs you can use a immediately invoked lambda expression to initzialize the object. As a simplified example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

struct ShaderProgram {
    ShaderProgram(const ShaderProgram&) = delete;
    ShaderProgram() {
        throw 1;
    }
};

int main(){


    ShaderProgram x = [](){
        try {
            return ShaderProgram{};
        } catch (...) {
            std::cout << "exception occured" << std::endl;
            std::terminate();
        }
    }();
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bW9zo3)

Comment: A question since I cannot elaborate this totally for the moment: That might not compile for pre C++17 compilers for the concrete class in doubt since it's actually copy-initialization and copy elision might not be applied here in doubt?

Comment: @Secundi yes, before C++17 copy elision was "only" an optimization, ie the object still had to be copyable, see here: https://godbolt.org/z/WqGxvq

Comment: I dislike having to use abort instead of return, since the terminal output becomes more daunting. But, it works and it does pretty much exactly what I want.

Comment: @Cherion actually `std::exit` might be more appropriate. I just thought that when anyhow you terminate due to an exception then it could be `std::terminate`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use try catch within the constructor itself? Try catch blocks should be applied as local to critical points as possible in general. Further on, referring to possibly not fully constructed this/objects is generally not a good idea and for the most cases at least undefined behavior.

**Update since you posted some more information:**

With a unique_ptr + factory scheme:

Provide the object you want to create via a factory pattern that forwards a unique_ptr to it so it's safe for each context where you want to use it and you do not run into unexpected behavior later on. Add a reference parameter to your constructor that tracks all the occurred issues so the factory method can forward this information. Return a nullptr for your error cases but forward the obtained errors always. As a failed construction seems to be a valid scenario for your (productive code) cases, it's totally valid to offer a dedicated error information here.

A solution without unique_ptrs:

Defer the critical parts of your constructor to an extra private method and apply the try catch there. Track the construction validity then simply via a failed bit/member. This ensures the validity of your object on the language layer of your issue but has some drawbacks since users might forget to check for the state depending on the usage context. Some parts of the standard io libs use this pattern.

Anyways, I prefer the unique_ptr solution.

Comment: So, how would I inform the constructor of the object that object construction failed and the object should not be used?

Comment: Forbid public construction this way completely, use a factory pattern in doubt that can provide this information for the "outer world". Since you do not allow copies, you might simply provide unique_ptrs as you already mentioned. That would also make things clearer for the users of your class.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a public 'init' function with arguments currently passed to constructor.
Create an empty 'ShaderProgram' with no arguments outside the try-catch block and call 'init' on it inside the block with the arguments.

```
public:
    ShaderProgram();
    ~ShaderProgram();
    // ! Might throw exception !
    int init(const std::string &vertexShaderPath, const std::string &fragmentShaderPath);
```

Comment: But that does not adhere to the RAII principle, which is something I really like. You are right that this works.